# play framework (2.3) - Getting asset URL from controller

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using iText to generate a PDF file in a controller, but I need to insert an image from the public assets in the file using it's URL. 
Is there any way to get the asset URL from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse routing works for assets just like for controllers. This should provide you with required information:

```
controllers.routes.Assets.at("images/unchecked.png").absoluteURL(request())
```

You can read more about it in the section **Reverse routing for public assets** of the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets).

Comment: That doesn't work: "error: no suitable method found for absoluteURL()".  The best I could find was   routes.Assets.at("public/images/unchecked.png").absoluteURL(request()); and that returns a wrong URL    http://localhost:9000/assets/public/images/unchecked.png instead of    http://localhost:9000/assets/images/unchecked.png