# Play Framework Java access public assets no method "at"

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am attempting I tried the following solution that I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251823/play-framework-2-3-getting-asset-url-from-controller/27252290#27252290):

```
controllers.routes.Assets.at("images/unchecked.png").absoluteURL(request())
```

but I am getting the following error :

> ```
> cannot find symbol
>   symbol:   method at(java.lang.String)
>   location: variable Assets of type controllers.ReverseAssets
> ```

which looks like it cannot find the `at` method, which I thought was built in.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you does not use "at" in the router, so it was not generated by Play.

I suppose you use versioned

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Change it to the "at" in the "routes" file, then rebuild the project

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

**EDIT:**

You will need to go by some "special" way if you want to use versioned in the routes (better and recommended way). Play (2.3 and 2.4) have an issue in Java (Scala version is correct) so Assets.versioned(String file) version is not present, only Assets.versioned(Asset asset) is available. So there is "special" way:

"routes" file:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

controller:

```
public Result index() {
    ...
    controllers.routes.Assets.versioned(toAsset("images/unchecked.png")).absoluteURL(request())
    ...    
}

public static controllers.Assets.Asset toAsset(String name) {
  return new controllers.Assets.Asset(name);
}
```

Look for an "Issue 3" in the [Play 2.3.3 Bugs](https://github.com/SocialFinance/play-2.3-java-reverse-routing/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me hours!